# understanding mount -o bind

Tags: linux

Few questions after the following commands:

```
mount -o bind /new_disk/home/user/ /home/user/

mount -o bind --no-mtab /new_disk/home/user/ /home/user/
```

1. What is the difference between the two commands other than " Mount without writing in /etc/mtab.  This is necessary for example when /etc is on a read-only filesystem."
2. What is the difference between mount -o bind and mount --bind ...if there are
3. Let's suppose i don't know there is a partition mounted using -o bind --no-mtab...where can I find if there is any mount point with bind ?
   The only way i can detect this is grep user /proc/mounts but in that line there is no info abut bind.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. None.
2. None.
3. Hmm, never knew that. You could find duplicate source devices and stat both mountpoints. If inodes differ, you have a bind mount:

   ```
   dennis@lightning:/tmp/foo1$ grep uuid /proc/mounts
   /dev/disk/by-uuid/ae2c3836-ea2d-4d0e-8409-75d682889d1f / ext3 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
   /dev/disk/by-uuid/ae2c3836-ea2d-4d0e-8409-75d682889d1f /tmp/bar1 ext3 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0

   dennis@lightning:/tmp/foo1$ stat -c %i /tmp/bar1 /
   1228938
   2
   ```

   However, if you bindmount one mountpoint to another (e.g. bindmounting `/` to `/tmp/bar1`), the inode numbers will be the same. Thus making it impossible to distinguish between a bind-mounted filesytem or a device simply mounted twice.

Comment: i hope there is a way of getting partitions mounted with bind if --no-mtab is given. I'll wait a few more days maybe someone will give me a hint :) but thank you for your explains

Comment: See [bind mounts, mtab and read-only](http://karelzak.blogspot.com/2011/04/bind-mounts-mtab-and-read-only.html), bindmount one mountpoint to another is identical to mount the same filesystem on two places, at least from kernel point of view.